# Semantic UI: Get clearing segment to expand to the height of it's contents

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm using a clearing segment to clear a floating button, but the segment does not seem to expand to the height of it's content.

How can I get it to expand it's height to fit the content?

Examples JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ftwL2whn/

```css
   /* View rubrics */
   
   .ui.centered.button-header.header {
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 1;
       right: 0;
       left: 0;
   }
   
   .ui.button.floated.button-header {
       position: relative;
       z-index: 2;
   }
   
   .ui.labeled.icon.button > .dark.icon {
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
   }
   /* Edit Rubric Input*/
   
   .edit.rubric.input {
       display: inline-block;
       margin: 0.2em;
       width: 250px;
   }
   
   .edit.rubric.wide.input {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 300px;
   }
   
   .edit.rubric.narrow.input {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 200px;
   }
   
   .edit.rubric.input input {
       border: none;
       width: 100%;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #D4D4D5;
   }
   
   .edit.rubric.input input:focus {
       outline: none;
       border-color: transparent;
       transition: 300ms ease all;
   }
   
   .bar:after {
       content: '';
       display: block;
       transform: scaleX(0);
       height: 2px;
       background: #48afb9;
       transition: 300ms ease all;
   }
   
   .edit.rubric.input input:focus ~ .bar:after {
       transform: scaleX(1);
   }
   
   .centered .edit.rubric.input input {
       text-align: center;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br>
<div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui top attached clearing segment">
        <h3 class="ui centered button-header header">
            <div class="edit rubric input">
                <input type="text" value="Phone QA">
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="sub header">
                <div class="edit rubric wide input">
                    <input type="text" value="Create and edit rubrics here">
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h3>
        <div class="ui left floated left labeled icon orange button-header button">
            Back
            <i class="dark left arrow icon"></i>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: You are trying to trying to get the `.button-header` to fit inside the `.segment`, correct? If you want to get super hacky, you can add `transform: translateY(-12px)` declaration to your `.ui.centered.button-header.header` rule.

Comment: I want to avoid the hackyness if at all possible, though if I end up having no choice I'll end up having to do something along those lines.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use flexbox?

Answer (score 0):

The clearing segment code that semantic added:

```
.ui.clearing.segment::after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
```

The issue is the third property of `height: 0;` If you open your dev tools and untick the selected height property, you'll see the height adjusting to cover 100% of the content.

One way to override this is to do something like this in your main CSS file:

```
 .ui.clearing.segment::after {
    height: 1.5em;
   }
```